# django admin url is inconsistent with custom primary key

Tags: django-admin

I've discovered when using a custom primary key in django admin, sometimes the assigned url is inconsistent with the id used.
When the primary key is **829_011**

```
class Run(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)

This url works:
https://localhost/admin/myapp/run/829_5F011/
but this does not - 404 error:
https://localhost/admin/myapp/run/829_011/
```

I don't know why django assigns an inconsistent url.
Does anyone know whether there is a simple fix for this?
Changing the model is going to be a major pain.

It's interesting that I consistently get the "5F" automatically put in the routing so if my primary key is 44_66 the url will end with 44_5F66.

Comment: what do you mean by does not work? Does is raise an exception, or 404,?? Also, Have you verified that an object with that ID indeed exists in the database?

Comment: That means if you put that url in the browser, the url router says that the page does not exist. This is a problem because some links would fail in that case...my primary key is 829_011

Answer (score 1):

This is simply a misunderstanding of how custom primary keys in Django admin work. Since you can put any characters, valid or invalid for urls, into a string primary key, Django has to encode these primary keys so that they do not confuse the admin url parser. This is described here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/utils.py#L63

The special characters `:` `/` and `_` are special characters in django urls, so for a primary key with the value `44_66` Django has to escape the `_` and this is why you see `44_5F66` in the url. The primary key in the database is still `44_66`.

Comment: It does not make sense to me because 829_011 encodes to 829%5F011 but the url that works was 829_5F011. Also the browser encodes automatically. Moreover, saw this behaviour with 829_011 but did not see it in another one like 824_123. Because it does not behave consistently, it makes no sense.

Comment: Like it says in the documentation I linked to: " Similar to urllib.parse.quote(), except that the quoting is slightly different so that it doesn't get automatically unquoted by the Web browser." so it's not standard url encoding. I haven't tested extensively so I don't know what can cause your inconsistency.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the schema which was a major work to avoid this inconsistency.
In short, do not use a string primary key with django.